# Any way to get java path used by tomcat/glassfish in web application

Tags: java

Title is pretty clear for my question, suppose I deployed an java application in tomcat/glassfish now for some reason I need java path used by respective server so is there any way to get java path which is used by server?

Comment: You mean java class path? You could try System.getProperty("java.class.path"); - see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `java.home` System Property, which should be exactly what you want:

```
System.getProperty("java.home");
```

Comment: What if java 7 and java 8 installed on system and server is using java 7. does `System.getProperty("java.home");` gives me java 7 only? according to me `java.home` will give java 8 path.

Comment: It will provide default jre's home path.

Comment: @SakibSami that may be java 8, but I want java path which is used by glassfish/tomcat. BTW `java.class.path` worked in case

Comment: then in tomcat settings
(`/etc/init.d/tomcat7`)
change in `JDK_DIRS="/usr/lib/jvm/default-java ${OPENJDKS} /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"`
set default jre to run tomcat in this case both will use default jre and your problem will be solved.